IBM ILOG CPLEX SheetConnection error message using flow control - Element "XYZ" not defined
I have programmed a .mod file for solving a flexible job shop problem and it runs perfectly just using it and the .dat file. Now, I am trying to modify the parameter A by using flow control in a .mod file; however, I am having an error indicating 'Element "outFile" not defined'. And it does not allow me to run the code. Does someone have any solution to it? And it happens with the other parameters bringing them from the SheetConnection, it indicates that none of them are defined.
I looked into Alex Fleischer's blog and other Stackoverflow questions but have not yet found any feasible/helpful answers. In the link you can find all the related files, the ranges are fine because it runs by itself without the flow control.
https://github.com/program1032/Optimization-Code/blob/129a5d1e3d180d5f396dac45c58ac0615fa79bc4/Data.dat

in IBM community , similar thread at https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/discussion/opl-reading-in-problem-parameters-from-multiple-files-in-a-loop
The flow control there:
main {
  var modelFile = "sched_jobshop.mod";
  var source = new IloOplModelSource(modelFile);
  var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);

  var number_of_problems = 4;
  for(var probno = 1; probno <= number_of_problems; probno++) {
  var cp = new IloCP();
  var theModel= new IloOplModel(def, cp);
    //var ifile = "input" + probno + ".txt";
    var ifile = "sched_jobshop_dat" + probno + ".dat";
    //Read input file
    //Create optimization model based on inputfile
    var data = new IloOplDataSource(ifile);
    theModel.addDataSource(data);
    theModel.generate();

    var result;
    var time0 = new Date();
    if (cp.solve()) {
      result = cp.getObjValue();
      var time1 = new Date();
      //Output file
      var ofileName = "output" + probno + ".txt";
      var ofile = new IloOplOutputFile(ofileName);
      if (!ofile.isOpen) 
        ofile.open(ofileName);
      
      //Save output such as objective function value
      ofile.writeln("Objective is ", result);      
      //time, number of nodes explored, etc
      ofile.writeln("solve time : ", (time1-time0)/1000);
      var nodes = cp.info.NumberOfChoicePoints;
      ofile.writeln("Number Of Choice-Points : ", nodes);
      ofile.writeln("====== All CP Info : ");
      for (var i in cp.info) {
        ofile.writeln(i + ": " + cp.info[i]);
      }
      ofile.close();
      writeln("Input " + ifile + " gave output " + ofileName);
    } else {
      writeln("Input " + ifile + " : Fail to solve.");
    }
    theModel.end();
    cp.end();
    data.end();
  }
  def.end();
  source.end();
}

